# jquery php not putting textfield value into url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a simple web page which takes the value from the input box and passes it to the next page or form. Only problem is I don't know how to use `jquery` to get the value and assign it as a `php` value. I want to pass this value in into the `URL`

EDIT THIS IS MY LATEST CODE:

```
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#usr").change(function(){
            var usr = $("#usr").val();
            $("#button").attr("href","calculate.php?id={45}&tt="+usr);
        });            
    });
</script>

    <?php
        print
            "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='usr'>".
            "<a id='button' href='calculate.php?id={45}&tt='><button class='btn btn-success'>Calculate</button></a>";

    ?>
```

When click the button it goes nowhere and no value is displayed in the URL

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `href` attributes don't do anything on a button, they can only be used on `<a>` linkes.

Comment: there is no element/tag there with the id of `button`. You are getting `#button` in jquery, but it doesn't exist so nothing is happening. Also, you don't usually wrap a button with an anchor (`<a>`) tag.

Comment: I see, so how do I link it to the button? Ideally I just want it to redirect to that calculate.php page with the value of the textfield

Comment: Looks like a good use for a form with `method="GET"`. It will get the form fields, like the `usr` field, and build the query string for you.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn sorry, but is that sarcasm? im new to web-dev so I wouldn't really know, I just researched it bit

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the ID in the `<a>` element whose `href` you want to modify.

```
<?php
    print
        "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='usr'>".
        "<a id='button' href='calculate.php?id={45}&tt='><button class='btn btn-success'>Calculate</button></a>";

?>
```

If you want to put a PHP variable in the jQuery code, you need to escape back to PHP from the HTML.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#usr").change(function(){
        var usr = $("#usr").val();
        $("#button").attr("href","calculate.php?id=<?php echo $values['test']; ?>&tt="+usr);
    });            
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, I modified your code a bit so that it was `href='calculate.php?id={$values["test"]}&tt='`. I then put that in the jquery and now it is not working - I suspect it is because of the $values["test"]. How do I include that in the jquery?

Comment: Is that in the HTML or jQuery?

Comment: in php file. the jquery doesnt work. if i manually add a value for the `tt` like say `calculate.php?id={$values["test"]}&tt=10` it works because i physically hardcoded in the file. if I type 10 in the textfield and click the button it is still like `calculate.php?id={$values["test"]}&tt=`

Comment: thanks but for some reason it is still not displaying the value. Is it something do with the button itself? Because if I hardcode the `href` of the button it works

Comment: Are you sure the variable is set correctly at this part of the script?

Comment: yes i am 100% positive. i dont get why the jquery is not working :(. I keep banging my head on the wall! As in the jquery url is not even being displayed at all!

Comment: only the buttons href is being used for some reason and not the jquery one

Comment: Are you sure the JS code is running? Any errors in the console?

Comment: I dont think it is, but how do I check?

Comment: Add an `alert` or `console.log` to the Javascript and see if it shows.

Comment: what do I just type that?

Comment: maybe it is because i am not prining the jquery stuff? also how will it know WHEN to run the jquery stuff - that being the button:

Comment: You don't need to print the jquery stuff, that's what `<?php echo $values['test'];` does. The jQuery stuff will run when you change the input field, because that's what `$("#usr").change()` means.

Comment: I think you need to study up on how all this works. I can't give you a full course in PHP and Javascript in the comments here.